# Unable to refresh the changed data in listview using notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `main activity` which has a `listview` which loads first and from this main activity I am launching a new activity where I'm trying to get the `edittext` value to my main activity by passing `intent`. Everything is working fine but when I add the editext value to the listview its adding but when I go to the `second activity` and add again and comes back to the main activity the previous added data is no more seen and the newly added value is updating the listview.

Can anyone help me out with this?

This is my Adapter:

```
public class AdapterListViewData extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context; 
    private ArrayList<DataShow> listData = new ArrayList<DataShow>(); 

    public AdapterListViewData(Context context,ArrayList<DataShow> listData) {

        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.listData = listData;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HolderListAdapter holderListAdapter; 

        if(convertView == null)
        {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_listview, null);

            holderListAdapter = new HolderListAdapter();

            holderListAdapter.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holderListAdapter.txtDetail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);
            holderListAdapter.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            convertView.setTag(holderListAdapter);
        }else{
            holderListAdapter = (HolderListAdapter) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holderListAdapter.txtTitle.setText(listData.get(position).getTitle());
        holderListAdapter.txtDetail.setText(listData.get(position).getDetail());

        holderListAdapter.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context,"CheckBox "+ position +" check!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context,"List "+ position +" click!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class CustomListViewActivity extends Activity {

    private AdapterListViewData adapterListViewData; 
    private ArrayList<DataShow> listData = new ArrayList<DataShow>();
    private ListView listViewData;
    String AddedTask ;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();



        listViewData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
        if (intent.hasExtra("NewTask")) {
             AddedTask = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("NewTask");
            listData.add(new DataShow(AddedTask,""));

       }
        adapterListViewData = new AdapterListViewData(getBaseContext(),listData);
        listViewData.setAdapter(adapterListViewData);
        adapterListViewData.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            Intent i = new Intent(CustomListViewActivity.this, AddTask.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

DataShow:

```
public class DataShow {
    private String title;
    private String detail;

    public DataShow(String title,String detail) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.title = title;
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getDetail(){
        return this.detail;
    }
}
```

Holder:

```
public class HolderListAdapter {
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDetail;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class AddTask extends Activity {
Button addtask;
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_task);

            // get action bar   
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

            // Enabling Up / Back navigation
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            addtask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnaddlist);
            findViewById(R.id.btnaddlist).setOnClickListener(
                      new View.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(View arg0) {
                              EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tskname);
                              Intent i = new Intent(AddTask.this,
                                      CustomListViewActivity.class);
                              //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                              String TaskName = edit.getText().toString();
                              //bundle.putString("NewTask", TaskName);
                              i.putExtra("NewTask", TaskName);
                              //i.putExtras(bundle);
                              startActivity(i);
                          }
                      });

          } 

        }
```

Comment: So essentially you are losing previous data, but your new data is getting updated?

Comment: I think you should startActivityForResult than startActivity for creating new Task. Now I believe you'll always have one task in your List. Right?

Comment: Is your previous data persistent, do you check it before you add it to the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old data got removed becaus it is not transmitted to the new activity that you start after creating the new item.

You should use `startActivityForResult` to create new task and call Add the new task to the list `adapterListViewData` in `onActivityResult` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should call `adapterListViewData.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside of

```
 if (intent.hasExtra("NewTask")) 
{
      AddedTask = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("NewTask");
      listData.add(new DataShow(AddedTask,""));
 }
```

That is,

```
if (intent.hasExtra("NewTask")) 
{
     AddedTask = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("NewTask");
     listData.add(new DataShow(AddedTask,"")); // you are adding new data here
     adapterListViewData.notifyDataSetChanged(); // just refresh the adapter here

 }
```

For debugging purpose, check what value you're getting for `NewTask` in `MainActivity.class`.

```
   Log.d("track",AddedTask);
```

DataShow class constructor expects a title and detail. Did you check whether it adds the value & you missed detail which is empty right?

```
listData.add(new DataShow(AddedTask,""));
```

Try supplying static data.

One more thing, **check whether your `adapter` is null** or **not** when adding new data send back from the secondActivity by,

```
  if (adapterListViewData != null) {
         AddedTask = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("NewTask");
  listData.add(new DataShow(AddedTask,""));
        adapterListViewData.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  else
   {
      adapterListViewData = new AdapterListViewData(getBaseContext(),listData);
        listViewData.setAdapter(adapterListViewData);
   }
```

Comment: tried with this too but the data is not being updated.

Comment: Yes I have checked with that. Even though I pass empty data the list is being updated with the new value but the old one is not showing up

Comment: @coder is your problem is not showing old data or not updating new data?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `adapterListViewData`  everytime your
onCreate is called that is why the previous data has been wiped out.
Add a checking in your onCreate to prevent this from happening.

```
if ( adapterListViewData == null )
{
  adapterListViewData = new AdapterListViewData(getBaseContext(),listData);
  listViewData.setAdapter(adapterListViewData);
}
```